# HP fortify XML External Entity Injection

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, fortify, xxe

Hp fortify shows me a XML external entity injection on the below code:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(sb);
xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, o);
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(stringWriter.ToString());  //bad code
result = xmlDoc.ChildNodes[1].OuterXml;
```

in the above it was showing the vulnerability in the following line **`xmlDoc.LoadXml(stringWriter.ToString());`**

How can I resolve this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use xmlDoc.XmlResolver = null; before loading the xml.

Answer (score 0):

The XmlDocument object has an XmlResolver object within it that needs to be set to null in versions prior to 4.5.2. 
In versions 4.5.2 and up, this XmlResolver is set to null by default.