# XML External Entity Injection : showing error on this line DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(sr));

Tags: java, xml

```
URL configurlURL = new URL(configurl.toString()); // validate
String domainConfig = get(configurl.toString(), headers, null);

// find and get the schema file from the reference url
Document doc = null;
try (StringReader sr = new StringReader(domainConfig)) {
    doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(sr));
}
```

Comment: XML parser configured in line 4 does not prevent nor limit external entities resolution. This can expose the parser to an XML External Entities attackUsing XML parsers configured to not prevent nor limit external entities resolution can expose the parser to an XML External Entities attack.

Comment: issue raised by HP fortify scan tool

Comment: already referred link but unable to solve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42125189/hp-fortify-xml-external-entity-injection